# horizontal alignment of multiple \pic objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I want to group some tikz drawings together, and am using a `pic` for this. I further wish to use the pics as though they're ordinary nodes, and draw some connecting arrows. How can I horizontally align the pics along the centre of their bounding boxes? I'd like to avoid specifying numerical coordinates. A cut-down version of my code is below.

It apears that specifying `right = of X` puts the pic's bounding box's `(0,0)` coordinate at that point, but I would rather have `(0, 0.5 * bounding box height)` at that point. I tried putting in some `anchor` options, but this didn't seem to have any effect---I guess the size of the pic's bounding box isn't known at the time when the pic is positioned.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    stack/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {#1}
            \draw [pic actions] (0+\i,0+\i) rectangle (1+\i,1+\i);
    },
    squares/.style={
        black,
        fill=orange!75,
    },
    edge/.style={
        ->,
        black,
        ultra thick,
        shorten <=1mm,
        shorten >=1mm,
    },
]
\pic [
    squares,
    local bounding box=A,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\pic [
    squares,
    local bounding box=B,
    scale=0.5,
    right= of A,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\pic [
    squares,
    local bounding box=C,
    scale=0.25,
    right= of B,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\draw [edge] (A) -- (B);
\draw [edge] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A-B-C]

Comment: It appears \pic always aligns the origin.  scopes have the same problem, and are best aligned using [shift=(...)].  Alas,by the time you can compute the dimensions, it is tool late.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to compute the size of something BEFORE you draw it, you need to use a savebox.  Either that or draw it twice.

Note replacing `[tikz]` with `\usepackage{tikz}` when using saveboxes.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\boxa}
\newsavebox{\boxb}
\newsavebox{\boxc}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\boxa}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    stack/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {#1}
            \draw [pic actions] (0+\i,0+\i) rectangle (1+\i,1+\i);
    },
    squares/.style={
        black,
        fill=orange!75,
    },
]
\pic [
    squares,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\savebox{\boxb}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    stack/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {#1}
            \draw [pic actions] (0+\i,0+\i) rectangle (1+\i,1+\i);
    },
    squares/.style={
        black,
        fill=orange!75,
    },
]
\pic [
    squares,
    scale=0.5,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\savebox{\boxc}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    stack/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {#1}
            \draw [pic actions] (0+\i,0+\i) rectangle (1+\i,1+\i);
    },
    squares/.style={
        black,
        fill=orange!75,
    },
]
\pic [
    squares,
    scale=0.25,
] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    edge/.style={
        ->,
        black,
        ultra thick,
        shorten <=1mm,
        shorten >=1mm,
    },
]
\node (A) {\usebox\boxa};
\node[right=of A] (B) {\usebox\boxb};
\node[right=of B] (C) {\usebox\boxc};

\draw [edge] (A) -- (B);
\draw [edge] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. It suggests that using pic at all may be the wrong approach. I'm going to keep digging through the pgfmanual to see if I find a neater alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one can place a tikz drawing (`\tikz \pic ...` in this case) inside the "text" section of a `\node`. Probably tikz already saves the node's text contents into a box (how else would tikz know how to anchor nodes at their centre?), so we can just reuse that to avoid doing our own `\savebox` dance.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0mm,
    stack/.pic={
        \foreach \i in {#1}
            \draw [pic actions] (0+\i,0+\i) rectangle (1+\i,1+\i);
    },
    squares/.style={
        fill=orange!75,
    },
    edge/.style={
        ->,
        ultra thick,
        shorten <=1mm,
        shorten >=1mm,
    },
]

\node (A) { \tikz \pic[squares] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}}; };
\node [right=of A] (B) { \tikz \pic[squares, scale=0.5] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}}; };
\node [right=of B] (C) { \tikz \pic[squares, scale=0.25] {stack={0,0.2,...,1}}; };
\draw [edge] (A) -- (B);
\draw [edge] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Calling tikz inside tikz is risky at best.